# docker python custom module not found

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker and trying to move one simple application to docker.
Python standard modules I am able to import using "pip install". However, I have some custom python utility files that I would like to use.
These files are in separate package "utils".

In my main python file : `test.py`, I am doing

```
from utils import math.py, logger.py
```

This outside of docker works fine, but when running through docker gives me the error `"ImportError: No module named utils"`.

My Dockerfile code:

```
FROM python:2.7.11
ADD ./ test_project/
WORKDIR test_project
ENV PATH=$PATH:/test_project/utils
ENV PYTHONPATH /test_project/utils

CMD [ "python", "report/test.py"]
```

---

My directory structure:

- `test_project`

  - `report`
  - `utils`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You set `PYTHONPATH` to `/test_project/utils`. When trying resolve the module `utils`, it is looking for one of:

- file `/test_project/utils/utils.py`
- directory `/test_project/utils/utils/` that contains `__init__.py`.

It looks like you have this?

```
utils/math.py
utils/logger.py
```

I wonder if what you really mean to do is

```
# different path...
ENV PYTHONPATH /test_project

from utils import math
from utils import logger
```

Comment: if I do `import math import logger` then my local environment is not able to resolve the module. It needs `from utils import math, logger`. So, to work on both local and in docker container, I need to have `from utils import main, logger`. are you suggesting to use `PYTHONPATH /test_project` so that it looks in directory `/test_project/utils/' that contains __init.py. ?

Comment: @Prashant I believe that is what you would want to do, yes.

Comment: And if there is not currently a `utils/__init__.py` then create it. It doesn't have to have any contents, just an empty file will work.

Comment: @Prashant updated my answer a bit to show fixed path etc.