# Python + Docker + No module found

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I have a functionality which is implemented using Python and Docker.

When I run `docker-compose up -d`, I am able to build image successfully and also the entire folder is copied into the Docker container and I am able to see the copied files in the container.

But, while running the Python file, I am getting the error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "bank_transactions"`

In file main_transactions.py, I have imported the constants file, I have shown the folder structure in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

When I run the app through PyCharm, it's working perfectly without any issue.

Below are the Docker file configs.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  app :
    build: .
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: testdb
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

COPY . /code/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 

CMD [ "python", "/Transactions/bank_transactions/main_transactions.py" ]
```

Error logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
app6_1  |   File "/code/bank_transactions/main_transactions.py", line 5, in <module>
app6_1  |     from bank_transactions import constants
app6_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bank_transactions'
```

Comment: First comment: the line `RUN mkdir /code` is unneeded, you can remove it (as `WORKDIR /code` can be seen as a Dockerfile equivalent of the bash command "`mkdir -p /code && cd /code`")

Comment: Then, the issue probably comes from a path issue: if you do `WORKDIR /code` and `COPY . /code`, **and** bank_transactions is in the root folder of the docker context (roughly, the folder that contains the Dockerfile), then you could try `CMD ["python", "/code/back_transactions/main_transactions.py"]`?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have removed "RUN mkdir /code" and I have added CMD ["python", "/code/back_transactions/main_transactions.py"] , and builded new image and run it, I am getting same error as ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "bank_transactions"

Comment: OK (BTW there was a typo in my comment, I had written "back_"…) but I guess you should add a bit more details in your question, maybe some part of the output of `docker-compose logs`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At first sight, the error you obtain in the logs

> […] Traceback (most recent call last):
> app6_1 | File "/code/bank_transactions/main_transactions.py", line 5, in `<module>`
> app6_1 | from bank_transactions import constants
> app6_1 | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bank_transactions'

suggests the file `main_transactions.py` is indeed parsed, which in turn imports the `constants.py` file, which fails.

Actually, this is related to the way `import` walks directories to find python packages and I'm pretty sure your error should vanish by setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY . /code/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 

ENV PYTHONPATH /code

CMD [ "python", "/code/bank_transactions/main_transactions.py" ]
```

For additional details, see [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41818226/9164010) (which dealt with Python2 − cf. the ImportError instead of ModuleNotFoundError with Python3 − but the fix should be the same).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am able to execute the code in docker , I am trying to understand why the issue is not giving with python django application where I have multiple modules import 
 and image is created with same docker file and run successfully.

Comment: This answer correctly answers the question. The only thing that needs to be changed is to add a `/` in the `COPY` step so that installing the requirements runs without error when building the Docker image, e.g. `COPY . /code/`.

Comment: @Martin [according to the doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) "If <src> is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are copied; If <src> is any other kind of file, it is copied individually along with its metadata. In this case, if <dest> ends with a trailing slash /, it will be considered a directory […]" so given <src>=`.` is a directory, the trailing slash seemed to be optional… but admittedly, adding a trailing slash cannot cause any harm, so I'll append this just in case :)

Comment: @ErikMD Thanks for the explanation! That makes sense and answers why I was running into this error during the `RUN` step when attempting to build the image: `ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/requirements.txt'`. I'd assume this is because (similar to @Suri) the <src>  that I am copying contains directories _and_ the `requirements.txt` file (outside of those directories), which might necessitate the trailing `/` in order to build successfully.